# Free installer that can install prequisites (.net framework, sql server)

Tags: c#, sql, installation

i've been googleing a bit, but can't fin anything useful.
I need a recomendation for a free installer for a c# app. The thing is, i'm using visual studio express edition and i'm makin a commercial product.
The express edition does not support the installer.
Basically, i need the installer to check for the .net frameword and sql server installed on the client computer. If it's there, install my app, if not, install that first and then my app.

Any advice / tip would be useful!

TNX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) installer.

Both are free and you can accomplish quite a lot with either.

> The Windows Installer XML (WiX) is a toolset that builds Windows installation packages from XML source code. The toolset supports a command line environment that developers may integrate into their build processes to build MSI and MSM setup packages.

---

> NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) is a professional open source system to create Windows installers. It is designed to be as small and flexible as possible and is therefore very suitable for internet distribution.